# @ModelAttribute return incorrect value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I send the value using the form:

```
<form action="user-fonts" method="post" ">
<select name="nameFont">
<#list fonts as font>
<option value=${font.id}>${font.nameFont}</option>
</#list>
</select>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <div><input type="submit" value="Go"/></div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping
    public String main(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model)
    {
       Set<DBFont> fonts = user.getFont();
        model.addAttribute("fonts", fonts);
        return "Myfonts";
    }
```

Here are the values in GetMapping:

[image]

```
    @PostMapping
    public String mainPost(@ModelAttribute DBFont DBfont)
    {

         return "redirect:/user-fonts";
    }
```

Why does namefont get id value? And Id = null?
is it possible to send all the class values?nameFont and ID?

[image]

Why am I getting null everywhere except for id?

Comment: I'd say that's because of `<select name="nameFont">`. With `<option>` you basically just send the value of the option back to the server which is the id in your case. Thus it should be `<select name="id">`.

Comment: Is it possible to send all the class values?nameFont and ID?

Comment: That should be possible but you'd probably have to change a thing or two (which also might depend on the web framework you're using): with traditional form data you'd probably have to add hidden fields for the additional values of the selected element (e.g. via JavaScript) or make the value of each option a complete representation of the selected element and parse that on the server. Alteratively you could ditch the form and post JSON data which would require even more JavaScript to build that on the client though.

Comment: ... However, imo the best option would be to just keep sending the id and look up the object on the server. That's less work to do, less error prone (what if the selection of a font would also change its name?) and more secure (again what if the name of the font or any other object you use that approach with would be changed in some malicious way?).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are not blocking any attribute in WebDataBinder.

```
@InitBinder
void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields("name", ...);
}
```

This method sets a restriction on fields that are allowed for binding. And all the other fields are unbound, naturally resulting in `null` values.

The other possible reason: incorrect setters in a Bean annotated with @ModelAttribute. For example, `Object setName(String name)` instead of `void setName(String)`.